# Where is "/var/log/messages" on mac-osx?

Tags: logging, mac-osx

When you read the man pages on Mac OS X, there are references to /var/log/messages, but if you look for the file, it doesn't exist:

```
$ ls -l /var/log/messages
ls: /var/log/messages: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you refer to the [man entry of syslog.conf](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/syslog.conf.5.html), I guess the line is just an **example**:

```
# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none          /var/log/messages
```

If you want to use that directory in your configuration, you'll have to create it.

Edit: The actual syslog.conf on Mac OS X uses the `system.log` file.

Comment: If you look at the actual /etc/syslog.conf instead of the man page, you see 
*.notice;authpriv,remoteauth,ftp,install.none;kern.debug;mail.crit   /var/log/sy
stem.log

Comment: Yes, as I said, the actual entry is system.log - NOT messages. It's in the *Example* section of man.

Comment: splattne: that was it, my system works the way you described it, I just didn't know where to look for the config.

Answer (score 11):

It's `/var/log/system.log` on Mac OS X. You're probably reading man pages from Linux based software which uses the `/var/log/messages` file instead.

Comment: I am reading the man pages that are pre-installed in Mac OS X.

They must be from the base UNIX distribution (some kind of BSD...)

Answer (score 1):

The var directory on Mac OS X is symlinked, if you do an ls -l on your root directory you'll see this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root   admin        11 22 Feb  2008 var -> private/var
```

So your var folder is located at:

```
/private/var/
```

However, I am unable to locate the messages folder or file within the log folder, so I can't help you with that part of the question.

Edit: On further inspection, it looks as though the only thing in /var/log/messages on my RHEL server is sshd warning logs. Maybe the Mac OS X sshd binary logs to

```
/private/var/log/sshd
```

or similar.

What messages are you looking for? You might want to try

```
$ cat /var/log/[process name]
```

and see if each process writes out its own message file.